# Enumerate through Grid cell in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid

I have Grid with 10 rows and 10 column, and I want in code behind get to every of this grid cell to change this background or add image to cell, How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid, in WPF, doesn't really have "cells".

Instead, individual child controls of the grid are "decorated" with the [Grid.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.row.aspx) and [Grid.Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.column.aspx) attached property.

If you want to change the color of a "cell", there will need to be some UIElement that is marked with that row and column, and is a child of the Grid.  You can search the grid's [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) for the specific control in that row and column (by using [Grid.GetColumn(child)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumn.aspx), etc), then set the color of that UIelement.